# How to extract multiple datasets from a larger dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence, credit-card

In python I am trying to prepare my data set. I want to train an LSTM, and will do so by training the model on all of the data grouped by credit card number and ordered by time.

For my test set, however, I want to create a set of sequences, that is a sequences of transactions for each client credit card number. So then with this I can test the model for individual clients, and not just random transactions.

To do this, I first extracted all credit card numbers from the credit card number column and added them to a list.

```
cc_list = df['cc_num'].tolist()
```

After I then got rid of any duplicates in the list, so that I was left with a list of all possible distinct accounts:

```
all_accounts = list(set(cc_list))
```

Then I tried to to create a new Dataframe for each account number in the list (which is approximately 900)

```
for acc in all_accounts:
y = df.loc[df['cc_num'] == acc]\
    .sort_values(by=['trans_date_trans_time'],ascending=True)
print(y)
```

However, this only gives me a Dataframe for the last account number, and not all.

I have also tried to define a function

```
accounts = df['cc_num'].unique()

def grouping_ccn(df):
    subset_values = []
    for acc in accounts:
        x = df.loc[df['cc_num'] == acc]\
            .sort_values(by=['trans_date_trans_time'],ascending=True)
        subset_values.append(x)
return np.array(subset_values)
groups_cc = grouping_ccn(df)
```

but this also didn't work, it gives an error saying: "ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2028 to array axis with dimension 22".
I see why I got this error, but I just don't know how to fix this.

- How do I properly extract a Dataframe for each individual credit card number?

I am a complete noob at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: standard rule: if you work with list (many values) then you need list to keep all results.

Comment: maybe better use `.groupby("cc_num")` to create groups but still works in one dataframe. Doc: [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). And if you have many DataFrame then you will have to `merge/join/append/concat` all to one DataFrames. Doc: [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: instead of `set()` you can use `df['cc_num'].unique()`

Comment: `sorted_groups = df.sort_values('trans_date_trans_time').groupby('cc_num')`

Comment: thanks @furas , however I have tried using groupby but it creates "pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy" and when I did sorted_groups.head() to see it as a Dataframe, it didn't properly group the data, the data was only ordered by time and the account numbers were still mixed with one another. I am trying to create a sequence of transactions for each separate account number, and then a set of all such sequences. To give more of an idea of what I am trying to do, above I added something else I tried (but didn't work). Possibly there is a completely different way of achieving this?

Comment: if you want only to sort by account and time then use `sort_values(['cc_num', 'trans_date_trans_time'])` without grouping. And if you want to do something more with every group then you could do `for val, group in sorted_groups: ... group ...`.

Comment: BTW: it can be easier if you give (in question) small example data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard rule: if you work with list (or dict) then you need list (or dict) to keep all results.

---

If you want every account keep in separated dataframe then you should append them to list and later use `for`-loop to work with every dataframe separatelly (one-by-one).

Or you could add to dictionary as `account: data` and later it could be simpler to get dataframe only for selected account - `dict[account]`.

To get unique accounts you can use `unique()` instead of `set()`.

But it could be simpler to use `groupby()` and later use loop to put every group in list or directory.

If you want to convert list with all dataframes back to one dictionary then you can use `concat()`.

---

Minimal working example with some data

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'account': ['A','B','A','C','B'], 
    'time': ['2022.02.20','2022.02.20','2022.02.19','2022.02.20','2022.02.10'], 
}

main_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print('\n--- main df ---\n')
print(main_df)

print('\n--- unique accounts ---\n')
print(main_df['account'].unique())

print('\n--- groups ---\n')

sorted_groups = main_df.sort_values(['time']).groupby('account')
all_dfs_list = []
all_dfs_dict = {}
for value, group in sorted_groups:
    print('-', value, '-')
    #print(group)
    print(group.reset_index(drop=True))
    all_dfs_list.append(group.reset_index(drop=True))
    all_dfs_dict[value] = group.reset_index(drop=True)

print('\n--- list ---\n')
for df in all_dfs_list:
    print(df)
    print('-')

print('\n--- dict ---\n')
for account, df in all_dfs_dict.items():
    print('-', account, '-')
    print(df)
    print('-')

print('\n--- concat groups ---\n')
print(pd.concat(all_dfs_list).reset_index(drop=True))

print('\n--- sort df ---\n')
print(main_df.sort_values(['account', 'time']).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Result:

```
--- main df ---

  account        time
0       A  2022.02.20
1       B  2022.02.20
2       A  2022.02.19
3       C  2022.02.20
4       B  2022.02.10

--- unique accounts ---

['A' 'B' 'C']

--- groups ---

- A -
  account        time
0       A  2022.02.19
1       A  2022.02.20
- B -
  account        time
0       B  2022.02.10
1       B  2022.02.20
- C -
  account        time
0       C  2022.02.20

--- list ---

  account        time
0       A  2022.02.19
1       A  2022.02.20
-
  account        time
0       B  2022.02.10
1       B  2022.02.20
-
  account        time
0       C  2022.02.20
-

--- dict ---

- A -
  account        time
0       A  2022.02.19
1       A  2022.02.20
-
- B -
  account        time
0       B  2022.02.10
1       B  2022.02.20
-
- C -
  account        time
0       C  2022.02.20
-

--- concat groups ---

  account        time
0       A  2022.02.19
1       A  2022.02.20
2       B  2022.02.10
3       B  2022.02.20
4       C  2022.02.20

--- sort df ---

  account        time
0       A  2022.02.19
1       A  2022.02.20
2       B  2022.02.10
3       B  2022.02.20
4       C  2022.02.20
```

---

Doc:

- [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)